# How to get the EXIF shutter count (imageNumber) using PHP?

Tags: php, image, metadata, exif

I've been able to get EXIF data by using `exif_read_data()`. According to the [EXIF documentation](https://exif.org/Exif2-2.PDF) provided on PHP docs, there has to be an `imageNumber` tag (I understand it's not guaranteed), but I haven't been able to see anything like that on my test image (Unedited JPG from a Nikon D5100). The same image seems to **carry** information about the shutter count as per online shutter count websites.

Really appreciate it if you can shed some light on what I'm possibly doing wrong to get this number. Or is there any other place or method they store shutter count in image meta?

**EDIT:**

Here's the code I tried to work out, and I'm trying to get `imageNumber` which is apparently not available to get. But online tools show the shutter count on the same image. I'd like to get the same result using PHP (or even using another language). Any help is appreciated.

```php
$exif_data = exif_read_data ( $_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name']);
print_r( $exif_data);
```

Comment: If you link to nothing (neither your file, nor one website) then this Q is too generic - people have to be able to **reproduce** what you experience. Metadata does not imply _Exif_, and enumerating all properties indirectly tells you which aren't used - there is no guarantee that the property [`0x9211 ImageNumber`](https://www.exiv2.org/tags.html) is stored.

Comment: @AmigoJack Please check the edit for the code. I couldn't find the originating point, that's why I didn't post the link before the edit. But here's the document it pointed to [Exif2](http://exif.org/Exif2-2.PDF) While I understand this `imageNumber` tag isn't guaranteed, somehow these online tools like [camerashuttercount](https://www.camerashuttercount.com/) show a shutter count on the same image. Do you have any idea how do they do it? Are there any other ways camera manufacturers store the shutter count?

Comment: Yes: in `0x927c MakerNote` (literal page 27, digital page 33 in the PDF) each manufacturer has its own proprietary structure to store data, for which you have to find good software which is able to read it (i.e. [ExifTool](https://exiftool.org)). Hence we need one example of your files (when uploading a picture to a picture hoster you have to check metadata like Exif isn't stripped).

Comment: @AmigoJack I have [uploaded an image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LxkNfjnQ5JO28_Z6h2pFNfDkXEdtdWf4/view?usp=sharing)  from the camera. Under the tag `MakeNote` it only has **Nikon** as the data. Please check my image and see if you get an idea of where to find the shutter count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your example file it is specific to *Nikon*'s `MakerNote` and in there specific to the *D5100* model. Using [ExifTool](https://exiftool.org/) in verbose mode shows the structure:

> ```
> > exiftool -v DSC_8725.JPG
> ...
> JPEG APP1 (65532 bytes):
>   ExifByteOrder = MM
>   + [IFD0 directory with 11 entries]
>   | 0)  Make = NIKON CORPORATION
>   | 1)  Model = NIKON D5100
> ...
>   | 9)  ExifOffset (SubDirectory) -->
>   | + [ExifIFD directory with 41 entries]
> ...
>   | | 16) MakerNoteNikon (SubDirectory) -->
>   | | + [MakerNotes directory with 55 entries]
> ...
>   | | | 38) ShotInfoD5100 (SubDirectory) -->
>   | | | + [BinaryData directory, 8902 bytes]
> ...
>   | | | | ShutterCount = 41520
> ```

- [JPEG](https://exiftool.org/TagNames/JPEG.html) explained, see segment `APP1`:

  - [Exif](https://exiftool.org/TagNames/EXIF.html) explained, see tag `0x927c`:

    - [Nikon's MakerNote](https://exiftool.org/TagNames/Nikon.html) explained, see tag `0x0091`:

      - [ShotInfoD5100](https://exiftool.org/TagNames/Nikon.html#ShotInfoD5100) explained, see index `801`

`MakerNote`s are proprietary: how data is stored there is up to each manufacturer. Documentations from those are rare - mostly hobbyists reverse engineer that information - that's why only selected software can read it at all for selected models. At this point you may realize that dozens of manufacturers with dozens of models exist, for which you all would have to interpret bytes differently - which is a lot of work! As per [`exif_read_data()`](https://www.php.net/exif_read_data#refsect1-function.exif-read-data-changelog)s ChangeLog *PHP* 7.2.0 nowhere claims to support *Nikon* at all.

You have to either parse the `MakerNote` yourself or find *PHP* code/library/software which already did that for you. As a last resort you could execute non-*PHP* software (such as *ExifTool*) to get what you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing knowledge and educating me in this regard. I understand the depth of the project and I was considering this as a pet project but understanding the scope of it, I will have to keep it away for a while it seems considering the limited time I have to spare atm. Thanks again for educating me here. Cheers mate!